# Django template -- no variable

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I am very sorry if this is a dumb question. I have tried to find a solution for several hours, and I am new and not very smart.

My webpage does not show the entire text. It only shows very little text.

views.py:

```
Create your views here.
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse


def testing(request):
    html = loader.get_template('testing.html')
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

testing.html

```
<html>


<body>


THIS IS A TEST PAGE. 


</body>

</html>
```

On my local server page, all I see is:  THIS IS'>

I don't see the rest. Can you please tell me what is wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: You're certain that it's picking up the template you think it is?

Comment: Hi Ignacio, thank you for your response.  yes, i am certain. I have changed it and it only shows the first few words. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render the template.  Change the last line to something like:

```
return HttpResponse(html.render(Context()))
```

You also need to import Context from django.template.  You might also want to consider using the render_to_response shortcut.  This stuff is covered in [part 3 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/#s-write-views-that-actually-do-something).

Comment: Thank you Vinay! That works really well! I did not know that context was needed if you don't have a variable. Thank you for clarifying, you really saved me a lot of frustration! Thanks again!